# Delegate add already handling event. Delegate remove not handling event

Tags: c#, events, delegates

I have a question related to delegate in C#.

1. What would happen if I use += on a delegate that already handling the event on the right side?
   EX:

   ```
    MouseDown += new MouseEventHandler(ShootOnMouseDown);
    MouseDown += new MouseEventHandler(ShootOnMouseDown);
   ```

What would happen at the second line?

2. What would happen if I use -= on a delegate that has not handled the event on the right side?
   EX:
   MouseDown has not handled ShootOnMouseDown, then:

   ```
    MouseDown -= new MouseEventHandler(ShootOnMouseDown);
   ```

What would happen then?

Thanks very much!

Comment: Why not write some code and try it yourself?

Comment: Yea I tried but it seemed to me nothing happened, so ... :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1- `ShootOnMouseDown` method will be invoked twice.

2- Nothing happens.